# glReadPixels get wrong data in android opengl es 2.0

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I get the yuv data from camera , and send them to opengl, then I use fragment shader to convert the data to RGBA format and show it on the screen. Everything goes well but when I use glReadPixels to get the RGBA data from framebuffer to int array, I get wrong data.

```
// I use VBO to draw
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVerticesBufferID);
glVertexAttribPointer(gvPositionHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(gvPositionHandle);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureVerticesBuferID);
glVertexAttribPointer(gvTextureHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(gvTextureHandle);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVerticesIndexBufferID);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

// Then I use glReadPixels to read the RGBA data
unsigned char *returnDataPointer = (unsigned char*) malloc(width * height * 4);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, returnDataPointer);
```

Unfortunately I get wrong data, the last thousands elements in the array are 0s,the same code works well on ios, did I miss something?

I work on Android 4.0.3 and use OpenGL ES 2 from the NDK.

Comment: Call glFlush before calling the glReadPixels?

Comment: also does glGetError report any errors?

Comment: glGetError report nothing, and I used glFlush before glReadPixels, the problem still exists. Do I use glReadPixels in a wrong way?

Comment: Only thing I can think is this from the doc: "GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION is generated if the currently bound framebuffer is not framebuffer complete (i.e. the return value from glCheckFramebufferStatus is not GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)."

Comment: glReadPixels() is known to have problems on some OpenGL ES implementations: not all pixel formats are supported.

Comment: I finally work it out. The size of glViewPort must be the same of framebuffer, or we will get wrong data.